# How to store HTML entity (dec) and hex on a PHP variable

Tags: php, html

I want to store the peso sign '₱' -  `&#8369;` inside a PHP variable.

Something like.. `$peso = &#8369;` ?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried lookin at [`html_entity_decode()`](http://in3.php.net/html_entity_decode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
  <?php
$peso = "&#8369";
echo html_entity_decode($peso);
?>
```